# Why can't I model my domain using ERD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, data-modeling, modeling

I am fairly new to this discussion but I HAVE to ask this question even at the risk of sounding 'ignorant'. Why is it that we now stress so much on 'DDD'. The more I look into 'DDD' the more complex it seems to make my application. Whereas modeling my domain with the database helps keep my application consistent across layers. Then I can use DAL Helpers such as SubSonic or L2S to easily access that model. What is so bad about this? Even in enterprise applications?

Why do we strive to create a new way of modeling our domain when we have a tried and tested one?

I am willing to hear from the purists here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a really excellent question, and the short answer is "you can."  We used to do it that way, and there was a whole area of enterprise (data) modeling.  In fact, the common OOD notations evolved from ERD.

What we discovered, however, was that data-driven designs like that had some difficulties, the biggest of them being that the natural structure for a data base doesn't necessarily match well to the natural structure for code.

OOD, to a great extent, derives from the desire to make it easier to find a code structure that has a couple of desirable properties:

- it should be easy to think out the design
- it should be robust under changes.

The ease to think out design comes originally from Simula, which used what we now think of as "objects" for simulation specifically; it was convenient in simulation to have software entities that correspond to the things you're simulating.  It was only later that Alan kay et al at Xerox saw that as a more general structuring method.

The part about robustness under changes had many parents, but one of the most important ones among them was Dave Parnas, you wrote several papers that identified a basic rule for modularization, which I call Parnas' Law: every module should keep a secret, and that secret is a requirements that is likely to change.

It turns out that by combining Parnas' Law with the Simula idea of a "object" as corresponding to something that can be identified with the real world, you *tend* to get system designs that are more robust under requirements changes than the old way we did things.  (Not always, and sometime you have to be crafty, as with the *Command* pattern.  Most objects are nouns, thing that have persistent existence.  In the Command pattern, the ideal objects are *verbs*, things you *do*.)

However, it also turns out that that structure isn't necessarily a good way to represent the underlying data in a relational database, so we end up with the "object relational impedance mismatch" problem: how to represent the transformation from objectland to database-land.

Answer (score 5):

You can't sell an old methodology, because too many projects failed and too many people know the old methodology anyway. There has to be a new one to market.

If you're doing fine with the old way then use what works. Do pay attention to new stuff, as some really nice ideas come along. But that doesn't mean everything old is bad and stupid. Usually you can incorporate new ideas into the old models to a large degree.

There *does* come a time to make a move. Like I wouldn't do OOP with structures and function pointers. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:  if all you need is a CRUD system that allows users to edit data, just build an Access front-end to your back-end database (or use a scaffolding framework like you mentioned) and call it a day.  You should be able to lop off 70% of your budget vs. a domain-driven system.

Long answer:  with a data-driven design, what does the implementation of the business model look like?  Usually after a couple years of building on new features to your application, you'll find that it's all over the place: tables, views, stored procedures, various application services, code-behind files, presenters/ViewModels, etc. with duplication everywhere.  When you're having a conversation with the domain expert about a new feature they are requesting, you are constantly trying to translate from the business language into the language around your implementation, and it just does not translate.

What typically ends up happening is that you are forced to communicate with the business in terms of the implementation of the system, and the implementation becomes the "ubiquitous language" that the business and developers are forced to use when communicating.  This has a wide range of consequences.  The domain experts in the business start believing that they are experts in the implementation domain, and they start demanding features in terms of implementation rather than the business need they are trying to solve.

Also, you'll find that most data-driven implementations do not follow the "conceptual contours" of the domain, and the components of the system aren't very flexible in how they can be combined together to solve the problem, because they don't map one-to-one with concepts in the business model.  When code isn't cohesive, changes and new features may require modifications all over your implementation.

Domain Driven-Design provides tools for making your implementation so closely resemble the business model that it's easy for everyone to speak the language of the business.  It allows you to write "executable specifications" that test your implementation, but can actually be understood by your domain experts.